# Pygame resizing a surface and window based on a rect size

Tags: python, pygame

I have a display area and a surface that is blitted on the display. On the surface is an image, in this case a rect. In the future it may be multiple rects or lines drawn on the surface keep that in mind.

I am trying to enlarge (by pressing x) the Rect named `Sprite` that is on `SpriteSurface` and `SpriteSurface` as well as the whole display window. The SpriteSurface image should be centered despite the resize. Currently the window will enlarge and the image stays centered, but if you uncomment the `spritesizeX` and Y lines the image gets larger but too big too fast and the window doesn't seem to enlarge big enough. Lowering the values shows that the offset of centering gets thrown off after the first resize. I feel like the solution should be relatively easy but im stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Settings.py

```
spriteSizeX = 30
spriteSizeY = 30
SpHalfX = int(round(spriteSizeX / 2))
SpHalfY = int(round(spriteSizeY / 2))
multiplyer = 3
windowSizeX = int(round(spriteSizeX * multiplyer))
windowSizeY = int(round(spriteSizeY * multiplyer))
HalfWinX = int(round((windowSizeX / 2) - SpHalfX))
HalfWinY = int(round((windowSizeY / 2) - SpHalfY))

Orange = (238,154,0)
Gold = (255,215,0)
Black = (0,0,0)
Blue = (0,0,255)
Gray = (128,128,128)
DarkGray = (100,100,100)
Green = (0,128,0)
Lime = (0,255,0)
Purple = (128,0,128)
Red = (255,0,0)
Teal = (0,200, 128)
Yellow = (255,255,0)
White = (255,255,255)

run = True
```

SpriteCapture.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from settings import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Sprite Capture")
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowSizeX, windowSizeY),RESIZABLE)
SpriteSurface = pygame.Surface((spriteSizeX,spriteSizeY))
Sprite = Rect(0,0,spriteSizeX,spriteSizeY)

while run == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]:
            pygame.image.save(SpriteSurface, 'img1.png')
            run = False

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_q]:
            run = False

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_z]:
            #spriteSizeX += 10
            #spriteSizeY += 10
            windowSizeX += -10
            windowSizeY += -10
            HalfWinX = int(round(windowSizeX / 2 - SpHalfX))
            HalfWinY = int(round(windowSizeY / 2 - SpHalfY))
            Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowSizeX, windowSizeY),RESIZABLE)
            SpriteSurface = pygame.Surface((spriteSizeX,spriteSizeY))

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_x]:
            #spriteSizeX += 10
            #spriteSizeY += 10
            windowSizeX += 10
            windowSizeY += 10
            HalfWinX = int(round(windowSizeX / 2 - SpHalfX))
            HalfWinY = int(round(windowSizeY / 2 - SpHalfY))
            Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowSizeX, windowSizeY),RESIZABLE)
            SpriteSurface = pygame.Surface((spriteSizeX,spriteSizeY))

    Sprite = Sprite = Rect(0,0,spriteSizeX,spriteSizeY)
    Screen.fill(Black)
    pygame.draw.rect(SpriteSurface,Orange,Sprite)
    Screen.blit(SpriteSurface, (HalfWinX,HalfWinY))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, it was late at night and i was very tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to scale your surfaces or rects according to the screen size, you can define a `zoom_factor` variable which you can just increase when a key gets pressed and then use it to scale the window and the surfaces. Multiply it by the original screen width and height to scale the window, and also scale your surfaces with [`pygame.transform.rotozoom`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotozoom) and pass the `zoom_factor` as the `scale` argument.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


width = 30
height = 30
multiplyer = 3
window_width = round(width * multiplyer)
window_height = round(height * multiplyer)
zoom_factor = 1
ORANGE = (238,154,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), RESIZABLE)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()  # A rect with the size of the screen.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Keep a reference to the original image to preserve the quality.
ORIG_SURFACE = pygame.Surface((width, height))
ORIG_SURFACE.fill(ORANGE)
surface = ORIG_SURFACE
# Center the rect on the screen's center.
rect = surface.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                run = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_z:
                zoom_factor = round(zoom_factor-.1, 1)
                # Scale the screen.
                w, h = int(window_width*zoom_factor), int(window_height*zoom_factor)
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), RESIZABLE)
                screen_rect = screen.get_rect()  # Get a new rect.
                # Scale the ORIG_SURFACE (the original won't be modified).
                surface = pygame.transform.rotozoom(ORIG_SURFACE, 0, zoom_factor)
                rect = surface.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)  # Get a new rect.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_x:
                zoom_factor = round(zoom_factor+.1, 1)
                w, h = int(window_width*zoom_factor), int(window_height*zoom_factor)
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), RESIZABLE)
                screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
                surface = pygame.transform.rotozoom(ORIG_SURFACE, 0, zoom_factor)
                rect = surface.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)
            # Note that the rect.w/screen_rect.w ratio is not perfectly constant.
            print(zoom_factor, screen_rect.w, rect.w, rect.w/screen_rect.w)

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(surface, rect)  # Blit the surface at the rect.topleft coords.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Alternatively, you could just blit all of your surfaces onto a background surface, then scale this background with `pygame.transform.rotozoom` each frame and blit it onto the `screen`. However, scaling a big background surface each frame will be bad for the performance.

Comment: Some key things for anyone that finds this useful. I omitted the RESIZABLE flag for the display due to it not being needed after testing it. Also i knew that i needed to update the variables on the change, but I forgot that its good practice to store an original of any object that will be going through changes. THANK YOU!! @skrx it works perfectly for

Comment: I also kept the call to draw to the smaller surface so that i can use a list to store a few different shapes or lines etc.